# Is it possible to listen to two dtsreams in single spark context?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, spark-streaming

I work with Spark 1.4.1. I want to listen to two different streams at the same time and find common events in both the streams.

For example: Assume one stream of temperature data and another stream of pressure data. I want to listen both the the streams and give an alert when both are high.

I have two questions

- Is it possible to process to two different streams in a single spark
  context.
- Is it possible to have multiple spark context with variable window sizes  in a single driver program.

Any other idea on how to work on the above situation will also be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple DStreams from the same StreamingContext.  E.g.

```
val dstreamTemp: DStream[String, Int] = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, "TemperatureData").map(...)
val dstreamPres: DStream[String, Int] = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, "PressureData")
```

They will both have the same "batch duration" as that is defined on the StreamingContext.  However, you can create new Windows:

```
val windowedStreamTemp = dstreamTemp.window(Seconds(20))
val windowedStreamPres = dstreamPres.window(Minutes(1))
```

You can also join the streams (assuming a stream of key-values).  E.g.

```
val joinedStream = windowedStreamTemp.join(windowedStreamPres)
```

You can then alert on the `joinedStream`.